# Casting error converting from unsigned int to uint16_t

Tags: c++

Why do I get this error

> 1>c:\users\g\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\tlvdemo\tlvdemo\tlvobject.cpp(50): error C2440: 'type
>   cast' : cannot convert from 'unsigned int (__thiscall
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::* )(void) throw() const' to
>   'uint16_t'

and how to fix it?

Code

```
uint16_t tagLen = (uint16_t)m_tagName.length; //m_tagName is string type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are calling the `length` method.

You have to use `m_tagName.length();`